# remove duplicate lines (only first part) from a file

Tags: list, awk, format, duplicates

I have a list like this

```
ABC|Hello1
ABC|Hello2
ABC|Hello3
DEF|Test
GHJ|Blabla1
GHJ|Blabla2
```

And i want it to be this:

```
ABC|Hello1
DEF|Test
GHJ|Blabla1
```

so i want to remove the duplicates in each line before the: |
and only let the first one there.

Comment: Notepad++ is not a programming language...

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Do you want to say these "duplicated" lines are consecutive?  All `ABC` lines go one under another? If yes, you can use `^(([^|\n]+\|).*)(?:\R\2.*)+` --> `\1` replacement in Notepad++.

Comment: You can provide suggestions on the provided answers, and it is found helpful, you can accept/upvote the answer, so that the post can be closed

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using `awk`

```
 $ awk -F"|" '!seen[$1]++ {print $0}' file
 ABC|Hello1
 DEF|Test
 GHJ|Blabla1
```

The trick here is to set the appropriate field separator `"|"` in this case after which the individual columns can be accessed column-wise starting with `$1`. In this answer, am maintaining a unique-value array `seen` and printing the line only if the value from `$1` is not seen previously.